# Torsion line bundles with non-vanishing cohomology on smooth ACM surfaces 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles, algebraic-surfaces

I am looking for an example of a smooth surface $X$ with a fixed very ample $\mathcal O_X(1)$ such that $H^1(\mathcal O(k))=0$ for all $k$
(such thing is called an ACM surface, I think) and a <s>globally generated</s> line bundle $L$ such  that $L$ is torsion in $Pic(X)$ and $H^1(L) \neq 0$.

Does such surface exist? How can I construct one if it does exist? What if one ask for even nicer surface, such as arithmetically Gorenstein? If not, then I am willing to drop smooth or globally generated, but would like to keep the torsion condition.

More motivations(thanks Andrew): Such a line bundle would give a cyclic cover of $X$ which is not ACM, which would be of interest to me. I suppose one can think of this as a special counter example to a weaker (CM) version of purity of branch locus.

To the best of my knowledge this is not a homework question (: But I do not know much geometry, so may be some one can tell me where to find an answer. Thanks.

EDIT: Removed the global generation condition, by Dmitri's answer. I realized I did not really need it that much.

Comment: Some (hopefully) positive criticism: You should add (edit) some discussion to motivate your question and show some thoughts/progress you have about it, even if it is very little.  This serves many purposes: 1) it gets people interested, 2) it shows you care about the problem (which I believe you do), and 3) it makes it easier for others to start working on it. 

Comment: I wonder what is so interesting about ACM surfaces (I'm sure there is something if you're asking)?

Comment: In general, ACM varieties have all the intermediate cohomolgy vanish. They correspond to Cohen-Macaulay rings, which have maximal depth, hence the name. From both algebraic (maximal depth) and geometric (no cohomology) I think they are nice. There are no wiki 
entry for them though (: 

Comment: What is the ground field that you consider in this question? If this is over $C$ and the surface is smooth then a globally generated torsion line bundle is trivial. 

Comment: Hi Dmitri! Would you explain or give a reference for that fact?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that by $\mathcal O(k))$ for all $k$ you mean powers of $O(1)$, where by $O(1)$ is some ample bundle over your surface $X$ (that you have right to chose)? This is not 100% clear from the question. And also you want your $L$ be torsion line, but not a trivial line bundle?

Comment: $L$ can't be trivial because of the condition on $X$. By torsion I just mean a torsion element in $Pic(X)$. 

Comment: From the definition of ACM surface, it follows that any smooth surface in characteristic zero with $h^1(O)=0$ is an ACM surface for some very ample bundle. Since this ample bundle plays no role in the subsequent part, it seems that you could simply assume that your surface has vanishing irregularity, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us show that a globaly generated torsion line bundle $L$ on a (compact) complex surface is trivial. Ideed, a globally generated line bundle has at least one section, say $s$. Let us take it. If $s$ has no zeros, then $L$ is trivial. But if $s$ vanishes somewhere then any positive power $L^n$ has a section $s^n$ that vanishes at the same points. So any power of $L$ is not trivial, i.e. $L$ is not a torsion bundle, contradiction.

Notice that we did not use the fact that the surface is smooth. And we also did not use the fact that we work with a surface...

Comment: Thanks! What about without the global generation condition? I realized I did not need it that much.

Comment: Dear Hailong, it will be very helpfull if you specify what you mean by $H^1(\mathcal O(k))=0$. For example is $k$ an integer number? In this case, can it be $0$? If it $k=0$, does this mean for you that $O(0)$ is just the structure sheaf of $X$? In this case it follows that your surface has $H^1(X)=0$. Also do I understand correctly that for you $mathcal O(1))$ is ANY ample line bundle? 

Comment: Dear Dmitri, I did mean all $k$(here I fixed a very ample line bundle $mathcal O_X(1)$). This is quite restrictive, I am aware of that.   